# How can I use a listview without extending ListActivity in my class?

Tags: android, listview

I have an application with various tabs (on a tabhost). Each tab is an activity that extends activity and has some `textfields` and things on it.

Now, I need that my tabs have inside a listview, but in the example from Android developer guide says that you have to extend ListActivity and not Activity.

Basically, I need to merge these two tutorials:

- *[List View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)*
- *[Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)*

How can I use a `listview` without extending `listactivity` on my class?

My XML file:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your TabHost can contain a `ListActivity` as well, since it inherits from `Activity`.

But, in case you want learn how to add a listview in an activity any way, follow these instructions. It's simple enough, Make an `Activity`, Add a `Listview` in your XML.

Use `findViewById()` to get your  `ListView`.

Comment: I am trying to do also with this way but i get an error too:

11-09 19:13:43.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(936): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @AndroidUser99, when using a `listactivity`, your xml must always have a listview whose `id` is `@android:id/list`

Answer (score 18):

It's almost the same. Basing myself on [ListView's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

Instead of doing:

```
setListAdapter();
```

do the following:

- Add a `<ListView>` in your layout
- create a field var in your `Activity` `private ListView mListView;`

on the `onCreate()` method do this:

```
 mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
 mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

I don't remember if `ListActivity` provides something more.

Comment: in wich part of my layout i have to add the listview?

Comment: ok i put it in the framelayout, but now i have another problem:

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);


I can't find my "your_list_view_id" ...

Comment: my listview id doesn't appear on my R autogenerated file Ç:S

Comment: in your layout (the file that you use in the `setContentView`) needs to have this: `<ListView android:id="+@id/your_list_view_id" ...`

Comment: it haves this:   <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"

but doesn't appear!

Comment: ok i solved it removing "android" word and putting only list as id... but now i have another problem, when im testing my app on the emulator, when it should show the tabs with the list, application crashes, with the thypical message, app stopped unexpectly etc..

Comment: 11-09 18:14:28.888: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 18:14:28.888: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(827):     at com.GPSLoc.AllActivity.onCreate(AllActivity.java:25)


line 25 is this line:   mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, USERS));

Comment: i dont know wich problem i have... maybe i dont have to put my listview inside framelayout in my tabwidget.xml? maybe i have to put in other zone? in wich one?¿

Comment: Edit your question with the xml

Comment: @AndroidUser99: There is no `<ListView>` there.