# Is it possible to use a ListView without ListActivity in Mono Android?

Tags: android, mono, android-widget, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement activity with ListView among other widgets. So if I understand correctly I can't use ListActivity (because it shows only one big ListView that ist ok for me).

I found a lot different examples of doing this in java  from SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133435/how-can-i-use-a-listview-without-extending-listactivity-in-my-class)
or
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity)
 or [great example](http://burakdede.com/2011/01/14/creating-custom-listview-in-android-application/).
I've tried to do in same way but it doesn't work correctly. I'm curious is this functionality exists in mono android at all?

I found only one example of using ListView in mono android which is 
[this](http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/List_View)
 and this example describe using ListActivity only.

So, my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</TableLayout>
```

My OnCreate:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CreateUser);

        JavaList<string> somadata = new JavaList<string> { "111", "222", "333" };

        ListView view = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
        view.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.CreateUser, somadata);
        view.TextFilterEnabled = true;          
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just found solution. I had error in this line:

```
view.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.CreateUser, somadata);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1) topic helps me a lot.

> Here is a further list of layouts that
>   you can [use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html).
>
> Sources of predefined layouts are [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/).

So, there is two options how to fix error and make ListView work without ListActivity in Mono Android.
First:
Just copy/paste layout of standard resource named `simple_list_item_1`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

Second (I'm sure it's a best way):
Just use standard resource. In Mono Android it named `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1`
So my updated version of OnCreate which works perfect:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CreateUser);

        JavaList<string> somadata = new JavaList<string> { "111", "222", "333" };

        ListView view = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
        view.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, somadata);
    }
```